# C programming strange output, what did I do wrong?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strlen

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 int j;
 char password[8] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'};
 j = strlen(password);
 printf("Size = %d\n", j);
 return 0;
}
```

Outputs:
Size = 8

But this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 int j;
 char password[8] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'};
 char enteredpassword[9];
 j = strlen(password);
 printf("Size = %d\n", j);
 return 0;
}
```

Outputs:
Size = 14

The difference between the two codes is that unused "enteredpassword[9]" array, is that supposed to change the string length of password[8] from 8 to 14?

Comment: Seriously... a very brief glance at the strings chapter in your C programming book would answer this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because strlen, null-termination etc

Comment: Nope, I couldn't find it, that's why I end up posting on this forum. Don't be mean.

Comment: Mean?   OK, what did you do to try to find out what the problem was.  Did you run your code under a debugger?  Did you look up strlen() and read about what it does?

Comment: I'm using linux and yes I use debugger and when I run it it says the output is 14, no error at all. That's why I got confused. I know what strlen() does but I tried to search what it does just to make sure in case I was doing something wrong. But I couldn't find anything about the null termination thingy, thanks for this forum and the good people out here I got the solution.

Comment: @MartinJames: if you don't want to help people who need help, then don't.  If everybody read everything there was about their problem before posting, we wouldn't have this site.  But sometimes people need a little help, and what seems trivial to you might be insurmountable to them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`strlen` expects a null-terminated string. Your character array lacks null terminator

```
char password[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '\0'};
//           ^^                                            ^^^^
j = strlen(password);
```

Calling `strlen` on a string that is not null-terminated is *undefined behavior*, meaning that your program could crash or return an unpredictable result. Note how the change removes the hard-coded length of the `password` array, letting the compiler figure out the correct size.

Comment: you cannot initialize an array of 8 elements with 9 elements.

Comment: @mch Ah, the copy-paste got me again! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've one question though, why did it work the first time? I did not use the null-termination but it outputs the correct number which is 8, why is that?

Comment: @GizachewMebratu The biggest problem with undefined behavior is that the program may appear working. This happens for a variety of reasons - for example, the next byte after the valid portion of your C string may happen to be zero, thus giving `strlen` the appearance of the string being null-terminated. Finding errors like that is not easy. It is best done using memory profiler, such as valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

Your `password` is not a null-terminated string.  If you initialize it conventionally:

```
char password[] = "abcdefgh";
```

or

```
const char *password = "abcdefgh";
```

then calling `strlen` on it will give you the expected answer.
(Or, if you're bound and determined to do it the hard way, use

```
char password[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '\0'};
```

or

```
char password[9] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '\0'};
```

.)

Answer (score 1):

Your program has invoked ***undefined behaviour*** , therefore , possible explanation is anything can appear as output (*if lucky you get seg fault*).

```
char password[8] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'};   //not a C-style string
```

`password` is not a null-terminated string and passing it to `strlen` will cause *UB*.

```
j = strlen(password);   //will invoke UB
```

Either write -

```
char password[9] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h','\0'};
```

or

```
char password[]="abcdefgh";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've one question though, why did it work the first time? I did not use the null-termination but it outputs the correct number which is 8, why is that?

Comment: @GizachewMebratu It inokes undefined behaviour . That means program can give any output . So it is possibility that it gave correct outpu , and second time it gave wrong answer . It might give a poem as output :-)

Comment: Probably it works last time because you got "lucky" and there happened to be a null at that location.  Note in debug mode, compiler writers often try to cause egregious undefined behavior to turn into crashes (so that you can fix them), though this is not guaranteed.  E.g., `char password[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'};int luck = 0;` **may** cause there to be a null adjacent to `password`,  All of this stuff is dependent upon numerous implementation details and cannot be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

The function `strlen()` is to be used with strings. In `C` strings are array of characters terminated by a `\0`. But your array is not `NULL` `\0` terminated.

Try the following

```
char password[9] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '\0'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior, since you're calling `strlen()` on arrays of characters that are not properly 0-terminated, i.e. they are not strings.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to initialize a string in C is something like that:

`char mystr[100]="test string";`

Because every string ends up with a NULL character ('\0'), so you must initialize your string like the following:

`char password[8] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '\0'};`

In this case, your password string was null-terminated and the strlen() will return the correct answer.